# Unit test case in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am new to AngularJS. I have learned some basic of it. Now, I need to work on a AngularJS project at my work. I needed to create a function which I have successfully created. Below is my method.

```js
vm.selectAll = function () {
    var items = this.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if ((vm.chkAll)) {
            if (!items[i].AssignedToZone) {
                if (!svcPermission.ensurePermission('AddPermission')) return;
                    svcZones.addPlace(Id, items[i].Id).then(refresh);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!svcPermission.ensurePermission('DeletePermission')) return;
                svcZones.removePlace(vm.selectedZone.Id, items[i].Id).then(refresh);
        }
    }

    angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        item.AssignedToZone = vm.chkAll;
    });
```

But , now my manager asked me to write unit test case for this method. I have googled it but I did not understand that from here I can start. I need to use Jasmine and mocha as these are already used it in current project.

Comment: Then look at some already existing tests to see how they work. Read documentation. Ask help to your colleagues so that they get you started. Or your boss.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am in different location and today is Saturday. I need to complete it by Monday. So, I am working on the weekend. If you can share better documentation link, that would be helpful for me.

Comment: If Saturday and Sunday are vacation days, you shouldn't be working for your boss. Just go see your boss on Monday, and tell him that you need help with tests. If he doesn't want to help you, then it shows he's not really interested in having the task done. If you're interested in how unit tests can be written, read the angularjs documentation and the jasmine documentation. It explains it.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I thought ppl helps here so I posted. Thank you for your suggestion. I will do it by my own.

Comment: Okay. I am going to read it. Thank you again

Comment: People help here with concrete programming questions. Broad questions like "how to write angular tests? Note that I didn't read documentation before asking" are way too broad, and show a lack of research, which is also required before posting.

Comment: Okay Sir. I am going to read documentation and I will come back with my specific questions.